# Django redirect to template passing model

Tags: python, django

The think I'm trying to do is to redirect to the same page where user was when  deleted an item. After delete using "django.views.generic.edit" (DeleteView) I can collect all needed information into model and get the specific category that I need. The question is how can I create this request url to go?

This way I get to http://127.0.0.1:8000/productlist/floor/

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'productlist' 'floor' %}" >
```

views.py

```
class LampDelete(DeleteView):
model = Lamp
#success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

def get_success_url(self):
    categ = self.object.category
    lamps = Lamp.objects.filter(category=categ)
    return redirect('productlist', {'lamps': lamps})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns =[
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^productlist/([a-z0-9]+)/$', views.productlist, name='productlist'),
url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
url(r'productlist/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', views.LampDelete.as_view(), name='lamp-delete'),]
```

So what method should I use and how to redirect to my template with selected category model. If somebody could provide an example would be very thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you still have object in `.get_success_url()`,

From [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L202-L225):

```
class DeletionMixin(object):
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Calls the delete() method on the fetched object and then
        redirects to the success URL.
        """
        self.object = self.get_object()
        success_url = self.get_success_url()
        self.object.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

As you can see, firstly it computes `success_url` and then it deletes the object.

**What you did wrong:**

1. Instead of supplying url as `str` object you called `redirect` which triggers redirect and skips the whole process of deletion.
2. Make `redirect` to view with url argument supplying `queryset` and not `str` as it has been waiting `([a-z0-9]+)`

I believe that in `productlist` view you expect some sort of name of category, by which your products been filtered

**So what you can do**:

1. Return valid `str` object in `.get_success_url()`

E.g.

```
class LampDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Lamp

    def get_success_url(self):
        category = self.object.category
        return reverse('productlist', args=[category])
```

Comment: category is already a Field from Lamp model, but when I pass only return reverse('productlist', {'category': category}) I get TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'. Even if category is <class 'str'>

Comment: @serj yes, that's because you need to pass `str` object that you use in `views.productlist`. i believe it could be name of `Category` object or something related to `Category` object

Comment: this is my views.productlist
def productlist(request, categ):
    MEDIA_URL = settings.MEDIA_URL
    lamps = Lamp.objects.filter(category=categ)
    return render(request, 'productlist.html', {'lamps': lamps, 'MEDIA_URL': MEDIA_URL})

wich object should I pass?

Comment: From your previous replies it's clear that `Category` is a django model. So you firstly need to get that object from `str` that you pass in your url as an argument, `lamps = Lamp.objects.filter(category__name=categ)` will do, but i strongly advise you to read whole [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/)

Comment: Sorry but Category is not a model, the only model I have is Lamp and it has a Field called category

Comment: @serj sorry i've not seen edit of your first comment and been misleaded by best practices. So i've edited my answer the last example part, i forgot the `.reverse()` method and that's why it havent work the first time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143585/discussion-between-serj-and-vishes-shell).